# Is there an equation for the space contained in the column space of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Surely my wording can use work but this is how I arrived at my question, and maybe it can help you understand what I'm trying to ask.

For my linear class, I have to show that $\vec{p}$ is in Col A. I took this question that $\vec{p}$ is in the span of the columns of A. For the problem, A=$\begin{bmatrix}-3&-2&0\\0&2&-6\\6&3&3\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&-3\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$. It can be seen that these columns only span $R^2$, but $\vec{p}=(1,14,-9)$ exists in 3 dimensions. The columns don't span $R^3$, but there are some vectors that have some magnitude in the z direction contained in the span of the columns. There are also vectors that arent contained in the span. My only tool thus far is to create an augmented matrix of [A p] and see if a solution exists, but I want to know all p.

**Therefore my question is:** Is there an equation(both for this question and in general) for the boundary separating the points contained in the span of columns and those not. I want a shape(3D in this case), or is this concept not a thing? I'm just thinking that since Col A spans $R^2$ and some space above(and im assuming below) that there is a set of all (x,y,z) in the span that creates some real shape that could be 3d printed and physically held. If this shape is possible to create, what general equation draws the boundaries of it where physical 3d printed greatness is tangible and everything else in $R^3$ that isn't the shape are points not contained in the span.

Maybe another way to ask is this: Some $n*n$ matrix's columns spans $R^{n-1}$ but not $R^n$. Vectors in the span have some magnitude in the nth dimension. Just how much space of $R^n$ does the span cover, and can this set of points be explained by a single equation? If so how do I find that equation.

I'm sorry for any wording or usage errors. This is only my second week in linear algebra. This thought has just been itching for a few hours.

Comment: Any proper subspace is a thin space, topologically - it is its own boundary. What is the boundary between a line and the rest of the plane?

Answer (score 1):

If $spa(A)<v_1..,v_n>$, then $x\in span(A) \iff Rank(x,v_1..., v_n)=dim(span(A))$. That gives you a system of equations for the subespace